# View Source Code causing change in my CSRF Token

Tags: php, security, csrf

I have a login form and I am using a hidden field in it and i am setting session with random value to avoid CSRF attacks, like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="valid" value="<?= $_SESSION['validation'] ?>">
```

This is how i set the $_SESSION['validation']

```
$_SESSION['validation'] = Hash::create('md5', rand(30, 3000), HASH_KEY);
```

When user logs in it checks that

```
if ($_SESSION['validation'] == $_POST['valid']) {
 //login
} else {
// Invalid Request
}
```

So when the user clicks on submit button on the login page, the value of `$_SESSION['validation']` will be compared for an extra security check. Now the problem is that, if open the Login Page and after that i open the View Source Code page and then i come back to login page and hit Login Button.

I am facing `"Invalid Request"` because opening view source code page changes the `$_SESSION['validation']` value, while over Login Page which we opened earlier has old `$_SESSION['validation']` value in the form as hidden value. How to cope with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in some browsers and situations, viewing source cause the browser to request a new copy of the page, rather than showing you the copy it already has. The same problem would arise if you opened two pages of the site in different tabs, which is a more likely scenario for your actual end users.

The main attack a CSRF token is protecting against is a link or form which wasn't loaded by the user at all, rather than one which was loaded too long ago, so you can improve things by keeping a list of recent tokens in the session, rather than only the most recent. You can associate an expiry time with each token, so a saved page can't be used hours later, and that also helps avoid issues with a user submitting something based on out of date data. You don't want the same token to be accepted twice, so remember to delete it from the list when it's used.

In some high-security cases, though, you might want to be strict and avoid any deeplinking, back/forward navigation, or tabbed browsing, so the current behaviour would be what you want. Many online banking apps do this, for instance, forcing a user to log back in if they navigate "in the wrong order", so somebody can't come to the computer after they've closed the window and continue the session.

Answer (score 1):

The same is applicable in the case of Captcha also. So end users won't do view source. The validation will go through normal.

If you still want to generate the same token, then while generating a new token follow this :

```
// Create a new CSRF token.
if (! isset($_SESSION['validation'])) {
    $_SESSION['validation'] = Hash::create('md5', rand(30, 3000), HASH_KEY);
}

//once validation is complete / successfully / failed then generate a new token
 if ($_SESSION['validation'] == $_POST['valid']) {
      $_SESSION['validation'] = Hash::create('md5', rand(30, 3000), HASH_KEY);
       //process the form data
  }
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3454607

Comment: Is there any way that if user view source code then my token do not get changed?

Comment: Follow the above approach if (! isset($_SESSION['validation'])) {
    $_SESSION['validation'] = Hash::create('md5', rand(30, 3000), HASH_KEY);
} . Draw back during page refresh also it won't change. We need to change this value during form submission.